# mysqltuner says my joins are not using index but I have index

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

I am very new to database design, I spun up an Ubuntu server version `20.04.3 LTS` and installed mysql version `mysql  Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`.

I designed my database like so

[image]

**addresses**

```sql
use `testdb`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `addresses`;

CREATE TABLE `testdb`.`addresses` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `street` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `country` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `coordinates` POINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `hash_UNIQUE` (`hash` ASC) VISIBLE,
  SPATIAL KEY `coordinates` (`coordinates`)
  );
```

**sales**

```sql
use `testdb`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sales`;

CREATE TABLE `testdb`.`sales` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `saleId` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `address_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `description` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `startDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `endDate` DATE NULL,
  `link` VARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `saleId_idx` (`saleId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `address_id_idx` (`address_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `sale_date_address_idx` (`address_id` ASC, `startDate` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `address_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`)
    REFERENCES `testdb`.`addresses` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

**images**

```sql
use `sales`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `images`;

CREATE TABLE `testdb`.`images` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
  `sale_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `sale_id_idx` (`sale_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `sale_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`)
    REFERENCES `testdb`.`sales` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

This is my first database design ever. I think my indicies are fine but I am not certain; when I run a query like the following

```sql
SELECT
    sales.id as id, BIN_TO_UUID(sales.saleId) as saleId, sales.title, sales.description, sales.startDate, sales.endDate, sales.link, sales.source,
    addresses.id as address_id, addresses.hash, addresses.street, addresses.city, addresses.state, addresses.zipcode, addresses.country, ST_X(addresses.coordinates) as latitude, ST_Y(addresses.coordinates) as longitude,
    GROUP_CONCAT(images.url) as images
from 
    sales
INNER JOIN 
    addresses ON sales.address_id = addresses.id
INNER JOIN
    images ON images.sale_id = sales.id
WHERE 
    sales.saleId = UUID_TO_BIN('8b56862c-47dc-49dd-9c82-b42c0e92d623')
GROUP BY
    id
LIMIT 
    1;
```

here is the execution plan
[image]

it executes fairly fast on around 5k records; however, when I run `mysqltuner` on my database I get the following:

```
...
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 18
...
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
```

Why does it say I am performing joins without indices when I am only using indices to perform my joins? I am lost, I have been researching without hope.

For reference here are my **mysqld** configurations

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
innodb_force_recovery = 0
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
binlog_expire_logs_seconds      = 86400

# mysqltuner.pl
skip-name-resolve=1
key_buffer_size=0
innodb_log_file_size=16M

# Suggested on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218250/help-with-mysqls-maximum-memory-usage-which-is-dang>
join_buffer_size=256K
thread_cache_size=40
#query_cache_limit=0
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100
key_cache_age_threshold=7200
key_cache_division_limit=50
key_cache_block_size=16K
open_files_limit=30000
table_open_cache=10000
table_definition_cache=2000
```

**EDIT: Running `EXPLAIN` on the query returns the following.**

**NOTE: I am using `MySQLWorkbench` to run my queries which is probably why it comes in a table format, not sure if I can output it in a different way**
[image]

Comment: The index presence does not mean that server will use it. It can be not applicable to your query. Or statistic may tell that the index usage will be less effective than the table scan.

Comment: *I think my indicies are fine but I am not certain; when I run a query like the following* You must look at the query EXPLAIN - it tells does the index is used, and when there is more than one index it tells what index is used.

Comment: For shown query - a composite index similar to `(saleId, address_id, id)` is suitable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I did add the compose but it seems as if `mysqltuner` still returning joins (not sure if I have to wait for reindexing maybe?) also I edited my question and posted a picture of the execution plan for that specific query and it seems like it is using the indices. I am not running any other query but that one. Alternatively, is it better to run multiple queries rather than joins? to build my aggregate on the server side? also I should add, I did restart mysql so maybe `mysqltuner` is returning inaccurate metrics?

Comment: Side issue:  A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` leads to getting an arbitrary row.

Comment: @Akina - Since `saleId` is `UNIQUE`, I don't recommend adding the 3-column index you mentioned.  (I do not have sufficient evidence to make a compelling argument either way.)

Comment: `address_id_idx` is unnecessary since it is the start of another index (`sale_date_address_idx`).

Comment: @RickJames Interesting point regarding the `LIMIT` I didn't know that. as far as the `address_id_idx` I thought by doing so I would benefit from running a query like this `SELECT * from sales where address_id = 10` but I understand your point. I still however wonder. Am I better off splitting my query into 2 queries from the client instead of a join? or can I improve this query where `mysqltuner` wont complain?

Comment: @RickJames I did some research about the `LIMIT` and I came to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812412/is-it-safe-to-use-limit-without-order-by so given I am searching by `Unique Index` do I even need limit? would it make my query faster? because using `Order By` will slow my query because it will do a sort but sort is not needed given my `saleId` is a unique index. This is just my hypothesis. In other words, how would it lead to getting arbitrary row if there could only be 1 single `saleId`?

Comment: @emhsmath - The optimizer will get rid of the `ORDER BY` if it picks an index that handles the ordering automatically.  Without the `ORDER BY`, the optimizer is free to scan the table, stopping when the `LIMIT` is satisfied.  This is fine (and likely to be faster) if you _do not care_ which ones you get.  I use such to get a feel for what is in a table; I do use `ORDER BY` when I want the "oldest" or "newest" or "biggest", etc.

Comment: Please provide the plain old `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` in text.  I have trouble with the graphical version.

Comment: @RickJames I understand, thank you for the explanation. Also I did update my post to include the plain `EXPLAIN` in text.